# Is it possible to Update Sharepoint List Without "ID"?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to Upload File on Sharepoint and while apploading only i want to add all properties of Uploaded Document.

We get ID field only when Document is uploaded on Sharepoint.
Is there any other way to Update List without passing ID Field.

Example:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1" 
ViewName="270C0508-A54F-4387-8AD0-49686D685EB2">
   <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID">4<Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>
   <Method ID="2" Cmd="Update">
      <Field Name="ID" >6</Field>
      <Field Name="Field_Name">Value</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

Refering [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx)

**** I am using Sharepoint Web Services.And Uploading Document in Chunks.****

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. First the file should complete uploading, then it will have properties that can be set! (otherwise properties may be set for non-existing files, in case that the file fails to upload.)